# Styling primeng autocomplete input

Tags: html, css, angular, styling, primeng

I would change the style of the [p-autocomplete](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete) component.

I used styClass

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="text" [suggestions]="results" (completeMethod)="search($event)"
[styleClass]="autocomplete"></p-autoComplete>
```

then in my css:

```
.ui-autocomplete .autocomplete  {
    border: 0px !important;
    background-color: green;
    box-shadow: none // delete the blue glow  when focus on input
}
```

I would delete the border and on focus enable border and disable blue glow effect.

I read the [theming documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/theming) and tried to do the same but I can't get it work

**Update** 
I make it partially work is used `ngdeep`

```
::ng-deep .ui-autocomplete-input {
    border: 0 ;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

For the second change (delete blue glowing and add border on focus ) it does not work.

```
::ng-deep .ui-inputwrapper-focus {
    box-shadow: 0;
    border: 2px;
}
```

Comment: just add class="autocomplete" in <p-autoComplete class="autocomplete"> tag